# error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive] C++

Tags: c++

no se cual es el problema, estoy hace un rato probando y no se como solucionarlo, a continuación el código, es para un ejercicio de la facultad pero sinceramente no entiendo nada, y esto lo añado solo porque me lo pide la pagina ahre jajajajaja, no se que mas detalle dar lpm ahr

```
void Ordenar(int n, int vec[])
{
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
            for(int f=0;f<n-k;f++)
            {
                if (vec[f]>vec[f+1])
                {
                    int aux;
                    aux=vec[f];
                    vec[f]=vec[f+1];
                    vec[f+1]=aux;
                }
            }
        }
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nEl valor de la posicion " << i << " es " << vec[i] << endl;
    }
}



int main()
{
    int n;
    int vec[n];
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "¿Cuantas posiciones tendra el vector? ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "----------------------------------------\n" << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese un valor para la posicion " << i << ":" << endl;
        cin >> vec[n];
    }

    cout << Ordenar(n, vec[n]) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo varias cosas que pueden estar sujetas al fallo.

1. Indudablemente tu manejo con punteros es pobre, y es normal cuando se empieza a programar en estos lenguajes. Por eso te aconsejo echarle un vistazo a la infinita documentación que existe en internet sobre punteros, acceso a regiones de memoria, etc. Porque a la larga te facilitará mucho entender cómo funciona todo y poder crear programas eficientes.
2. Cuando creas el array `vec`, le das un tamaño de `n`. Pero en ese momento del programa, la variable `n` no tiene valor, no está inicializada ni asignada, por lo tanto el tamaño del array es impredecible. Debes crear el array `vec[n]` una vez que se sepa el valor de `n`.
3. En el la parte de código donde introduces los valores que forman el array `vec`... Date cuenta que estás completando un array con la variable `n`, cuando en realidad `n` es fija y la variable que recorre el array es `i`, por lo que debes introducir los valores en `vec[i]`.
4. Tu última instrucción: `cout << Ordenar(n, vec[n]) << endl;`, dentro de la función `Ordenar` ya estás imprimiendo los valores dentro de la llamada a la función, por lo que no necesitarías sacar por el terminal los resultados de la función ordenar.

Con estas cosas, el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


void Ordenar(int n, int *vec)
{
    for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
            for(int f=0;f<n-k;f++)
            {
                if (vec[f]>vec[f+1])
                {
                    int aux;
                    aux=vec[f];
                    vec[f]=vec[f+1];
                    vec[f+1]=aux;
                }
            }
        }
    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nEl valor de la posicion " << i << " es " << vec[i];
    }
}


int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "----------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "¿Cuantas posiciones tendra el vector? ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "----------------------------------------\n" << endl;

    int vec[n];

    for (int i=0; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Ingrese un valor para la posicion " << i << ":" << endl;
        cin >> vec[i];
    }

    Ordenar(n, vec);

    return 0;
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: 1. Efectivamente de Punteros no se mucho ya que ando atrasado con la materia, sin embargo el tipo queria que lo hicieramos sin punteros pq este punto nos lo dio antes de enseñarnos punteros jajajajajaj                                                                                           3. Si, me daba una especie de error y yo no entendía porque, no me contaba la cantidad de espacios, si ponia a n como 5 solo me dejaba ingresar 2 valores, imagino q era por el 2do punto q pusiste, muchas gracias y un saludooo